# how to avoid high memory consumption in itextsharp

Tags: vb.net, itext

Here AddPage() method consuming more memory(In Bytes[]) while creating pdf.And it is not freed up after creating pdf.I tried with freereader() method but not useful.Please suggest how can i free memory or way to consume less memory

```
Public Sub AddStampedPagesToDocument(ByVal stamperStream As MemoryStream)
    Dim documentReader As PdfReader

    If stamperStream IsNot Nothing Then
        mStamper.FormFlattening = True
        mStamper.Close()
        documentReader = New PdfReader(stamperStream.ToArray)

        If (mOutputWriter Is Nothing) Then
            mOutputDocument = New Document(documentReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))
            mOutputWriter = New PdfCopy(mOutputDocument, mOutputStream)
            mOutputDocument.Open()
        End If

        For pageCount As Integer = 1 To mFormReader.NumberOfPages
            mOutputWriter.AddPage(mOutputWriter.GetImportedPage(documentReader, pageCount))
            mOutputDocumentPageCount += 1
        Next

        mStamperStream = stamperStream
        mOutputWriter.FreeReader(documentReader)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What version of iTextSharp are you using?

Comment: version i am using is iTextSharp 4.1.6